# Making a code that will add unique characters to a list

Tags: python

so the below code should be talking the unique characters in msg and the unique characters and making a list containing two sublists. An example would be

```
crack_the_code('hello there', 'abccd eabfb')
```

should return

```
[['h', 'e', 'l', 'o', 't', 'r'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']].
```

What I have tried to do below is made three lists and then ran a for loop to check if i is in the new list (unique) if not adds it to the list, same was done for unique_code.

Then finally put the two lists together and returned but when I print I get none. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def crack_the_code(msg, code):
    unique = []
    unique_code = []
    cracked = []
    for i in msg:
        if i not in unique:
            unique.extend(i)
    for item in code:
        if item not in unique_code:
            unique_code.extend(item)
    cracked = unique.append(unique_code)
    return cracked

print(crack_the_code('hello there', 'abcd eabfb'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Swap your extend with append and your append with extend. I think you got them confused in terms of functionality.

You append an element to a list.
You extend a list to another list.

Also, you used [item] in the second for loop but you were adding [i] into the list. Change that to [item] then below code works:

```
def crack_the_code(msg, code):
    unique = []
    unique_code = []
    cracked = []
    for i in msg:
        if i not in unique:
            unique.append(i)

    for item in code:
        if item not in unique_code:
            unique_code.append(item)        

    cracked = unique + unique_code

    return cracked

print(crack_the_code('hello there', 'abcd eabfb'))
```

Comment: By some slight weirdness in the OP's code it does not matter that they confused the two. When fixing the return like I did it works, because in `unique.extend(i)`, `i` is a single character, but strings are iterable...

Answer (score 2):

You get `None`, because `unique.append(unique_code)` mutates `unique` and does not return a modified list, but `None` (as all functions mutating the input should). You can do `return [unique, unique_code]` instead.

---

After having fixed your return, you should use a better algorithm. Whenever you check `if i not in unique`, this linearly checks the list `unique` for the value `i`, making it `O(n^2)` in total.

This is using the [`itertools` recipe `unique_everseen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), which keeps the original order and is `O(n)`, because it uses a `set` to keep track of already seen letters:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add

    for element in filterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
        seen_add(element)
        yield element

def crack_the_code(msg, code):
    return [list(unique_everseen(msg)), list(unique_everseen(code))]
```

If you cannot use `itertools`, you can also write it yourself (probably slightly slower):

```
def unique_everseen(iterable):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add

    for element in iterable:
        if element not in seen:
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
```

And if you don't care about the order, just use `set`:

```
def crack_the_code(msg, code):
    return [list(set(msg)), list(set(code))]
```

Comment: I unfortunately have not learned how to use the itertools yet, and thus would not be able to answer the question with it, however the over solution you offered works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Meliodus123: Added an implementation of `unique_everseen` without using `itertools`.